# Loading Wordpress Site Inside iframe won't allow users to login

Tags: nginx

I'm loading my wordpress website inside of an iframe.

However, on Chrome, I cannot login to the Worpdress site when it is inside the iframe. I've been pushed in the direction of a reverse proxy, but wondering if there are any other solutions?

I've tried the following:

It will load after changing the http headers, but the login issue still persists. I changed them to this:

```
proxy_cookies_flags ~ secure samesite=none;
add_header Set-Cookie "Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None;

add_header X-Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors https://examroom.ai";
add_header X-Content-Security-Policy "frame-src https://examroom.ai";
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://examroom.ai";
```

Comment: why are you loading your site inside an iframe? This has major SEO performance and security repercussions. If you can provide some context for why you have this setup it will influence the answers you get greatly, right now there's a very high chance you'll get an answer that is technically correct but doesn't solve your problems

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have users that have to take exams and I have to load my exam inside of the iframe of the exam proctoring company.

Comment: it's very possible that the problem you're having is deliberate and by design of the proctoring company as an anti-cheating mechanism. E.g. you can setup an iframe to allow scripts but block cookies like this `<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src="..."></iframe>`, and if the proctoring companys software does this then there is nothing you can do from your end without their involvement, and no way for people online to help you